# Let $K$ be a simplicial complex. If $L$ is a subcomplex of $K$ , then $\left|L\right|_{d}$ is a closed subset of $\left|K\right|_{d} $ .

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $K$   be a simplicial complex. If $L$   is a subcomplex of $K$  , then $\left|L\right|_{d}$   is a closed subset of $\left|K\right|_{d} $ .

Some definitions:

A **simplicial complex** is defined to be a set $K$ consisting of finite sets called **simplices** such that every subset of a simplex is also a simplex. A **vertex** of $K$ is defined to be a simplex containing only 1 point. We denote the set of all vertices of $K$ by $V(K)$. A **subcomplex** $L$ of a simplicial complex $K$ is a subset of $K$ that is a simplicial complex itself. We define $\left|K\right|_{d} $ to be the  set of all functions $\alpha:V\left(K\right)\rightarrow [0,1]$
  such that

1. $\left\{ v\in V\left(K\right):\alpha\left(v\right)\neq0\right\} \in K$
   , and
2. $\sum_{v\in V\left(K\right)}\alpha\left(v\right)=1$.

We can define a metric $d$ on $\left|K\right|_d$ by $d\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\sqrt{\sum_{v\in V\left(K\right)}\left[\alpha\left(v\right)-\beta\left(v\right)\right]^{2}}$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\left|K\right|_d$. So $\left|K\right|_{d} $ is now a topological space. If $L$ is a subcomplex of $K$, then we can can consider  $\left|L\right|_{d} $ as a subspace of  $\left|K\right|_{d} $ in the following way. If $\alpha\in\left|L\right|$
 , then $\left\{ v\in V\left(L\right):\alpha\left(v\right)\neq0\right\} \in L$
 , and $\sum_{v\in V\left(L\right)}\alpha\left(v\right)=1$
 . Now define a function $\alpha':V\left(K\right)\rightarrow [0,1]$
  by $\alpha'(v)=\alpha\left(v\right)$
  for all $v\in V\left(L\right)$
  and $\alpha\left(v\right)=0$
  for all $v\in V\left(K\right)-V\left(L\right)$
 . Then $\alpha'\in\left|K\right|_d$
 .

These definitions are all introduced in Spanier's book. He claims that if $L$   is a subcomplex of $K$  , then $\left|L\right|_{d}$   is a closed subset of $\left|K\right|_{d} $. I tried proving it, but could not do it.

Comment: Take a function $\alpha \in |K|_d \setminus |L|_d$. Then, it follows that $S = \{v\in V(K) : \alpha(v) \neq 0\} \in K\setminus L$. Now, define $U = \{\beta\in |K|_d : \beta(v) \neq 0 \text{ if } v \in S\}$. The set $U$ is clearly(? maybe a short argument is needed) open in the metric topology, and it follows that $\alpha \in U$ and $U \subset  |K|_d \setminus |L|_d$.